# VPN Basic setup help

Tags: networking

Can anyone tell me a few steps to set-up a simple VPN,
to secure my email.I have tried various servers/PPTP 
none work.The connection keeps getting disconnected.

Comment: How do you configure your VPN server ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

What follows are the absolute minimum instructions that you need to get a basic PPTP VPN server running under Ubuntu. Clients will then be able to VPN into the server and route their internet traffic so that it goes through the server to the internet.

First, install the required software:

```
sudo apt-get install pptpd
```

Second, enable `ip_forward` in the kernel for `IPv4` by uncommenting the associated line in `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
sudo sed -i -r 's/^\s*#(net\.ipv4\.ip_forward=1.*)/\1/' /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Reload the config file to have the change take effect immediately.

```
sudo -i sysctl -p
```

Third, enable `NAT` (if it isn't enabled already) so that users on the private VPN network can have their packets routed out to the internet:

```
OUTIF=`/sbin/ip route show to exact 0/0 | sed -r 's/.*dev\s+(\S+).*/\1/'`
sudo -i iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface $OUTIF --jump MASQUERADE
```

Enable NAT on boot from the rc.local script.

```
CMD="iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface $OUTIF --jump MASQUERADE"
sudo sed -i "\$i$CMD\n" /etc/rc.local
```

Note: This guide assumes you have no firewall configured on the server. If you have a firewall on the server, such as `UFW`

Fourth, for each `VPN` user, create an account in the file `/etc/ppp/chap-secrets`.

Replace `$USER` with the actual username you want to use for that VPN user.

```
KEY=`head -c 20 /dev/urandom | sha1sum | nawk '{print $1}'`
echo "$USER pptpd $KEY *" | sudo tee -a /etc/ppp/chap-secrets
```

Comment: PPTP is not that secure anymore

Comment: My Home Router , uses DHCP, a Class C range.The internal ip range gets changed to an external dynamic IP , will this cause a problem with enabling NAT ?I use GUFW. If PPTP is not secure what else do I use ?